# Pass Multidimensional array value in dropdownlist

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm creating an ajax function to retrieve product details from mongoDb.

The array structure is:

```
Array
(
   [PRD20160830063407] => Array
    (
        [_id] => PRD20160830063407
        [tpl] => Array
            (
                [ProductName] => Adidas Agro-Yellow,Gray
            )

    )

[PRD20160831104319] => Array
    (
        [_id] => PRD20160831104319
        [tpl] => Array
            (
                [ProductName] => sera xv001s
            )
    )
)
```

Need to pass _id, ProductName in a Select Box value and data part, I do not know how to retrieve the multidimensional array..

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: please mention your programming language.i did not get in which one you want to do this.

Comment: using Ajax     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            url: baseUrl + "/Product/GetProductDet",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
                
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
Array Return Above result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (I'm not aware of the notation you used to show us the array), you're actually having problems with accessing the **associative array** because the data is not in `array[0]`, `array[1]`, etc. but in `array[PRD20160830063407]`, etc; which means that you cannot iterate using the common for-loop.

You need `Object.keys(array)` to iterate over them.

```
var IDs = [];
Object.keys(array).forEach(key => {
    IDs.push(array[key]['_id']);
});
```

Comment: You might want to update your question then because it's not obvious what you're asking. What have you tried? Give a concrete example using the common JS notation we can all understand.